# Chain Matrix Multiplication Schedule Cost

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

If I have the matrices M0, M1, M2, M3 with the dimensions 10×1, 1×2, 2×1, 1×10 respectively.
I am getting the same cost for two different cases, is this possible or am I doing something wrong?
M03 = (M0x(M1xM2)xM3) = 112

M03 = ((M0xM1)xM2)xM3 = 112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost to multiply two matrices `i x j` and `j x k` is `i * j * k`.

For your first example, the cost is 2 + 10 + 100 = 112.
For your second example the cost is (10 * 1 * 2) + (10 * 2 * 1) + (10 * 1 * 10), or 20 + 20 + 100 = 140.

It's possible that depending on the dimensions, the order would not matter. In this case it does.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But if I use the equation $N_{i,j}=min_{i\leq k<j} {N_{i,k} + N_{k+1,j} + d_{i}d_{k+1}d_{j+1}}$ for calculating the optimal subproblem costs. I keep getting the same cost for both.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (and I don't know what that equation is supposed to be doing). If you aren't getting the right answer for cost, something is wrong in either concept or implementation.

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't explain my self well enough, also it doesn't help that I don't know how to use the markdown formatting for comments. I'm trying to understand the algorithm described in the image here [link](https://imgur.com/a/AeN5eg6). (from the Algorithm Design_ Foundations, Analysis, and Internet Examples [Goodrich & Tamassia 2001] book). I can post a picture of my calculations later if that helps.

Comment: That's an algorithm to find the minimal cost of a chain multiplication, not the cost of a specific case. The minimal cost for this chain multiplication is 112 and it occurs for the first case above.